# Multivariate change of variable, shouldn't this Jacobian be diagonal?

Tags: statistics, derivatives, change-of-variable, jacobian

I'm trying to understand [this](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Eliam/teaching/neurostat-fall13/papers/brown-et-al/time-rescaling.pdf) paper, at some point the author applies a multivariate change of variable and I can't really understand why the Jacobian should be triangular instead of diagonal, here are the important passages directly from the paper:

---

Joint probability density of exactly $n$ events times:

\begin{equation}\label{26}
\color{black}{f\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, \ldots, u_{n} \right)}
=
\color{black}{\prod_{k=1}^{n} \lambda\left(u_{k} \mid H_{u_{k}}\right) \exp \left\{-\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_{k}} \lambda\left(u \mid H_{u}\right) d u\right\}}
\end{equation}

We define the transformation

\begin{equation}\label{28}
\Lambda\left(u_{k}\right)=\int_{0}^{u_{k}} \lambda\left(u \mid H_{u}\right) d u
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tau_{k}=\Lambda\left(u_{k}\right)-\Lambda\left(u_{k-1}\right)
\end{equation}

for $k=1, \ldots, n$.

Then, by the *multivariate change-of-variable* formula (Port, 1994), we have that

\begin{equation}\label{212}
f\left(\tau_{1}, \tau_{2}, \ldots, \tau_{n}\right)=|J| f\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, \ldots, u_{n}\right)
\end{equation}

where $|J|$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix $J$ of the transformation between $u_{j}, j=1, \ldots, n$ and $\tau_{k}, k=1, \ldots, n$.

Because $\tau_{k}$ is a function of $u_{1}, \ldots, u_{k}$, $J$ is a *lower triangular* matrix, and its determinant is the product of its diagonal elements defined as $|J|=\left|\prod_{k=1}^{n} J_{k k}\right|.$

---

***My question is: why should J be a lower triangular matrix?***

***J should be something like***

\begin{equation*}
J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial \tau_1} & \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial\tau_2} & \dots &\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial\tau_n} \\
\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial \tau_1} & \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial\tau_2} & \dots &\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial\tau_n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial \tau_1} & \frac{\partial u_n}{\partial\tau_2} & \dots &\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial\tau_n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

***We have:***
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\color{red}{
\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial \tau_{k-1}} = \left(\frac{\partial \tau_{k-1}}{\partial u_{k}}\right)^{-1} \\
\frac{\partial \tau_{k-1}}{\partial u_{k}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial u_{k}}\int_{u_{k-2}}^{u_{k-1}} \lambda\left(u \mid H_{u}\right) du = 0
}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

***and:***

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\color{red}{
\frac{\partial u_{k-1}}{\partial \tau_{k}} = \left(\frac{\partial \tau_{k}}{\partial u_{k-1}}\right)^{-1} \\
\frac{\partial \tau_{k}}{\partial u_{k-1}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial u_{k-1}}\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_{k}} \lambda\left(u \mid H_{u}\right) du = 0
}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

***So my guess is:***

$$
J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial \tau_1} & \color{red}0 & \dots & \color{red}0 \\
\color{red}{0} & \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial\tau_2} & \dots & \color{red}0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & \dots &\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial\tau_n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

*What am I doing wrong?*

---

Edit: I fixed the paper link.

Moreover, I'm not sure that $\frac{\partial u_{k-1}}{\partial \tau_{k}} = \left(\frac{\partial \tau_{k}}{\partial u_{k-1}}\right)^{-1}$ and $\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial \tau_{k-1}} = \left(\frac{\partial \tau_{k-1}}{\partial u_{k}}\right)^{-1}$ hold in this case.